# psycopg2 выборка данных в определенном диапозоне

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Как в psycopg2 сделать выборку данных из таблицы в определенном диапазоне, к примеру от 4 до 8. На подобии как SQLITE3 работает LIMIT, т.е. вот так: *cur.execute('SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 4, 8')*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор OFFSET позволяет указать, с какой строки надо начинать выборку.

```
SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3;
```